# Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

Tags: .net, multithreading, httpwebrequest

I am bit hitting the wall on this, I have piece code which multiple thread make web request

```
 var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
                    request.Accept = "application/xml";
                    request.Method = shopfiyRequest.ActionType.ToString();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(shopfiyRequest.ContentType))
                        request.ContentType = shopfiyRequest.ContentType;

                    // authentication
                    var cache = new CredentialCache();
                    cache.Add(uri, "Basic", new NetworkCredential(apiKey, password));
                    request.Credentials = cache;

                    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);


HttpWebResponse response = null;

                        Log.Debug("Getting responsce from shopify");
                        // This is where the HTTP GET actually occurs.
                        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

As soon as the thread hitting the line `response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();` it throws following exception

**Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.**

[I have tried catching and ignoring abort exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982949/error-unable-to-evaluate-expression-because-the-code-is-optimized), but seems no avail

any help help or inside in this would be appreciable.

Comment: Just to update on what I found, it seems this something to do with Vs debugger. This happens only when I was trying to debug. but when Application compiled and ran in release, everything worked fine. May this happening due to vsdubugger tries to shut the some threads that are invoked. (which I am not quite sure). This may not be the right answer but it may help someone!